# How can I change a setting in the Glusterfs plugin for Docker?

Tags: docker, glusterfs

I want to change a configuration in a docker plugin, I read [this manual](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/plugin_set/), and I use this command:
`docker plugin set glusterfs:latest Config.PropagatedMount=/opt/docker/data/427680.427680/volumes/`

but I'm getting this error when I want to change this configuration `"PropagatedMount": "/var/lib/docker-volumes"`:

`Error response from daemon: setting "PropagatedMount" not found in the plugin configuration`

My problem is probably with the JSON format, but I couldn't find a way to set this setting.

This is the docker plugin inspect output:

```
[
    {
        "Config": {
            "Args": {
                "Description": "",
                "Name": "",
                "Settable": null,
                "Value": null
            },
            "Description": "GlusterFS plugin for Docker",
            "DockerVersion": "18.03.0-ce",
            "Documentation": "https://github.com/trajano/docker-volume-plugins/",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/glusterfs-volume-plugin"
            ],
            "Env": [
                {
                    "Description": "",
                    "Name": "SERVERS",
                    "Settable": [
                        "value"
                    ],
                    "Value": ""
                }
            ],
            "Interface": {
                "Socket": "gfs.sock",
                "Types": [
                    "docker.volumedriver/1.0"
                ]
            },
            "IpcHost": false,
            "Linux": {
                "AllowAllDevices": false,
                "Capabilities": [
                    "CAP_SYS_ADMIN"
                ],
                "Devices": [
                    {
                        "Description": "",
                        "Name": "",
                        "Path": "/dev/fuse",
                        "Settable": null
                    }
                ]
            },
            "Mounts": null,
            "Network": {
                "Type": "host"
            },
            "PidHost": false,
            "PropagatedMount": "/var/lib/docker-volumes",
            "User": {},
            "WorkDir": "",
            "rootfs": {
                "diff_ids": [
                    "sha256:9e8240f5b99231266ccb3260422fa333d6f72b3d7f6c77042d775ffc0e89b9ba"
                ],
                "type": "layers"
            }
        },
        "Enabled": false,
        "Id": "1401d85f492bdaa6be658068fed13362f1507224e0ccf349d5e3a1e47c570f9b",
        "Name": "glusterfs:latest",
        "PluginReference": "docker.io/trajano/glusterfs-volume-plugin:latest",
        "Settings": {
            "Args": [],
            "Devices": [
                {
                    "Description": "",
                    "Name": "",
                    "Path": "/dev/fuse",
                    "Settable": null
                }
            ],
            "Env": [
                "SERVERS=gluster-01,gluster-02,gluster-03"
            ],
            "Mounts": []
        }
    }
]
```

Do you have any idea how to change a docker plugin setting?